# Changing content on fragment by previous button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I'm new here!
Hope you could help me out!

I'm trying to do something smart. There is my "Article.java" fragment and I want it to take me to another `Fragment` when I click on one of the `ImageButton`s that are inside my Article's layout (fragment_article.xml).

The problem is that I want it to change the content of the upcoming fragment by the choice I made on the Article.java (for each `ImageButton` I want a different text). I really don't know how to do it.

I thought about making a some strings with my texts and somehow use `setText()` to set it by the `ImageButton` choice, but I really don't know how to do it.

So I guess I need your help here with that.
**How do I change the text by the image button choice on the previous fragment by only using one java class and multiple strings?
Maybe there is a smarter way?**

**Also see there is `setTitle()` method and I want to change it too by that choice.**

Here is Article.java:

```
public class Article extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false);

    }

    public void handleOnBackPress() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Home screen: Articles");
        imageButtonListener();

    }

    public void imageButtonListener(){
        ImageButton button1 =(ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.SugarButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottomtop, R.anim.topbottom,R.anim.popbottomtop,R.anim.poptopbottom);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
     }
    public void imageButtonListener(){
        ImageButton button2 =(ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.SugarButton);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottomtop, R.anim.topbottom,R.anim.popbottomtop,R.anim.poptopbottom);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is ArticleFragment.java (the one fragment with dynamically changeable text):

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.articlefragmentviewer, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("article Title");
        TextView article = new TextView(getActivity());
        article.setText("Hey");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To init fragment with some data just add static factory method:

```
  public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM = "content";

    private String title;
    private String content;

    /**
     * Static factory method that takes a String parameter,
     * initializes the fragment's arguments, and returns the
     * new fragment to the client.
     */
    public static ArticleFragment newInstance(String title, String content) {
        ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM, content);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM_TITLE);
            content = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articlefragmentviewer, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle(title);
        TextView tvArticle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_article);
        tvArticle.setText(content);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Providing static factory methods for your fragments is good practice because it encapsulates and abstracts the steps required to setup the object from the client.

To instantiate fragment, instead of:

```
Fragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
```

you have to use a factory method:

```
Fragment fragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance("Some content goes here");
```

Also, pay attention that you need to init view in "`onCreateView`" method and not in "`onViewCreated`".

Extract method to init fragment:

```
private void openArticleWith(String title, String content){
            Fragment fragment = new ArticleFragment.newInstance(title, content);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottomtop, R.anim.topbottom,R.anim.popbottomtop,R.anim.poptopbottom);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And your button listener will be:

```
public void imageButtonListener(){
    ImageButton button1 =(ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.SugarButton);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           openArticleWith("This is title for first button", "This is content for first buttton");
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: I see but what I ment is that the TextView and the setTitle will be change not by id of a view ..
I want it to be changed based on the ImageButton on Article.java fragment that the user clicks.
for example:
user clicks button 1 so it takes to the ArticleFragment with a title belongs to the button 1 and a text that belong to button 2 etc.
Edited the question!

Comment: Right, for this just use factory method. Extract your fragment initialization into a method with parameters like this:
`code
void openArtickleWith(String title, String content){
      Fragment fragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance("Some title", "Some content goes here");
      // code to commit fragment...
}
`

And on button click listener just call this method with needed params

Comment: Didn't really understand.. could you add it to the code maybe? sry for the inconvenience

Comment: Just updated my answer. Listener for the second button will be just the same but with different content.

Comment: glad I could help.